# CSS color bug in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

I am currently working on a site at: http://hverdagskupp.no/v4/

I have a CSS problem specific to Chrome. The navigation on the site is made with the following markup:

```
<nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Alle tilbud</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Bunnpris</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Europris</a></li>
               ...
            </ul>
</nav>
```

I have the following CSS to make the links color #555:

```
nav li a {
color: #555;
display: block;
padding-left: 25px;
}
```

However, when Chrome renders the site, its with the color #222. It says in the inspector that its #555, but its really #222. Chrome is the only browser that interpets the code this way.

Please inspect the code to see what i mean.

Does anyone know why Chrome does this? Or it it a bug in my code?

Thanks!

Added a screenshot. As you can see its actually close to #000. Im using Chrome 8 for MAC.
[image]

Comment: They look the same to me (Firefox 4 and Chrome 8) but there are slight differences in the hues of the greys and blues. Try starting Chrome with --enable-monitor-profile in case this is a color management issue. Also, FWIW when I dynamically query the computed style of the links, I get back "rgb(85, 85, 85)", or #555, which correlates with the inspector (which has been buggy before!).

Comment: have you tried using 6-digit hex values instead? (eg `color: #555555;`)

Comment: Looks correct to me. Using Chrome v8 on OS X I turned up the font size, screenshotted the "Bunnpris" nav item, and sampled the screenshot in Photoshop. I get a value of `#56585a`. I think you need to specify your OS and Chrome version, and supply a screenshot of what you are seeing.

Comment: Ok, added a screeshot. Im using Chrome 8 for MAC

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Chrome doesn't seem to happen to me see: 
**Edit:**
I can see the color change

[image]
[image]

Comment: But the inspector is lying. Try disabling the color: #555. The color stays the same (cos its really using #222)

Comment: Same thing here on Chrome 8.0

Comment: It could be a MAC only problem

Answer (score 0):

It isn't using #222, it is using the #000000 that you specified on the line 2 of "style.css".

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i found the sinner:

```
a:visited {
color: inherit;
}
```

This obviously caused this problem, which only occurred on Chrome for MAC.